# parse xml files and perform pass/fail test --Linq to xml?

Tags: c#, parsing, linq-to-xml, xml-parsing

So what I need to do is parse xml files and extract out data from the file and with the value I extract out I need to have the code determine whether it passed or failed the test.

for example: 
I extract out XMax and it needs to be less than 200 and if it is it passed if its higher it failed.
I extract out XMin and it needs to be more than -200 and if it is it passed if its less it failed.
I extract out YMax and it needs to be less than 200 and if it is it passed if its higher it failed.
I extract out YMin and it needs to be more than -200 and if it is it passed if its less it failed.

here is what the xml file looks like with the values i need to check:

```
<XAxisCalib>
      <Max>288.46</Max>
      <Min>-46.6</Min>
    </XAxisCalib>
    <YAxisCalib>
      <Max>646.76</Max>
      <Min>-89.32</Min>
    </YAxisCalib>
    <ZAxisCalib>
      <Max>19.24</Max>
      <Min>-143.63</Min>
```

Anyone have suggestions on what to you to write the program I was thinking linq to XML to parse the files and data out  but now sure how I can compare the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ to XML sounds fine to me, yes. Something like:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
int xMax = (int) doc.Root.Element("XMax");
int yMax = (int) doc.Root.Element("YMax");
int xMin = (int) doc.Root.Element("XMin");
int yMin = (int) doc.Root.Element("YMin");

return xMax < 200 &&
       xMin > -200 &&
       yMax < 200 &&
       yMin > -200;
```

If that's not the sort of thing you were thinking of, please give more details.

EDIT: If the problem is having four different tests, you'd want something like:

```
public bool ValidateXMax(XDocument doc)
{
    int xMax = (int) doc.Root.Element("XMax");
    return xMax < 200;
}
```

... but repeated four times. Of course the repetition is slightly ugly, as is the hard-coding of the values, but it's unclear what you're trying to do, to be honest. Another alternative:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
int xMax = (int) doc.Root.Element("XMax");
int yMax = (int) doc.Root.Element("YMax");
int xMin = (int) doc.Root.Element("XMin");
int yMin = (int) doc.Root.Element("YMin");

bool xMaxValid = xMax < 200;
bool yMaxValid = yMax < 200;
bool xMinValid = xMin > -200;
bool xMinValid = yMin > -200;
```

Comment: No that seems like its getting their so the code needs to check the file and call for the xmax and xmin's... and if its higher than the value it failed and if it's lower it passed. Where you wrote:

    return xMax < 200 && 
       xMin > -200 && 
       yMax < 200 && 
       yMin > -200;

Is this returning the value extracted?  I would just like to determine if it passed or failed.

Comment: @Casey: That's returning whether or not it passed the test. It's extremely unclear what you mean at the moment to be honest. Please spend some time clarifying your question, and read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Are you familiar with the error "since program returns void, a return keyword must be followed by the object expression."

Comment: @Casey: Can't say it rings a bell, but if you'd show the code that's failing, that would help. You haven't really described what you're trying to do very clearly yet - I've shown my best guess at something to help you, but you really need to give more details. Did you read the link from my previous comment?

Comment: Oh yes thank you for the link: so what I need to do is look at the xml files and check to make sure the xmax value is below 200 and xmin is higher than -200 and ymax is below and Ymin is higher and the code should return a pass or fail if its true or not for each case.

Comment: @Casey: Okay, so you'll want four different methods instead of one method - but you should be able to extract that easily from what I've shown. Which part is confusing you?

Comment: no what you've written is great and it seems obviously clear what its doing so what I'm not seeing is where it actually writes pass/fail for the tests after it validates that the value is higher or lower than the set value.

Comment: @Casey: It captures that value as a `bool`. I assume you can manage printing out "pass" or "fail" depending on a `bool` condition...

Comment: oh haha yes sorry. Thank You!

Comment: When I build the program to test it starts running and gets to the line : int xMax = (int) doc.Root.Element("XMax");  
and says the value can't be null

Comment: @Casey: Well does your document have an `<XMax>` element? I was just guessing at the format, as you never provided any sample XML...

Comment: oh shoot you know what it doesn't I remember chatting with you a few days ago I will update my original post with an example of the xml file.

Comment: @Casey: You're kidding me, right? You expect me to remember the details of every question I've answered in the last week or so, down to the format of a file used? If I've already answered a question on that file format, I've probably given an example of how to access the right values - so reuse that code here. I don't have time to spoon-feed you every single bit of code... you've got to put in some effort too.

Comment: Jon I wasn't blaming you or saying you needed to remeber it was more of an AHH moment for myself. Sorry.

Comment: @Casey: Ah, sorry, I misread your comment as "Surely you remember..." - oops :)